# designing table for high insert rate

Tags: t-sql, database-design, indexing

I would like some sugestion on how to design a table that gets like 10 to 50 million inserts a day and needs to respond quickly to selects... should i use indexes? or the overhead cost would be too great?

edit:Im not worried about the transaction volume... this is actually a assigment... and i need to figure out a design to a table that "must respond very well to selects not based on the primary key, knowing that this table will receive a enourmous amount of inserts day-in-day-out"

Comment: If this is homework then it should be tagged as homework.  50 K a day is not enormous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely. At least the primary key, foreign keys, and then whatever you need for reporting, just don't overdo it.  10k-50k inserts a day is not a problem. If it was like, I don't know, a million inserts then you could start thinking of having separate tables, data dictionaries and what not, but for your needs I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Best rate is PK sort the same as the insert order and no other indexes.   10-50 thousand a day is not that much.   If only inserts then I don't see any down side to dirty reads.

If you are optimizing for select then use row level locking for inserts.

Measure index fragmentation.  Defragment the indexes on a regular basis with a proper fill factor.   Fill factor determined the how fast the indexes fragment and how often you defragment.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did 50,000 per day and your day was an 8 hour work day, that would still be less than two inserts per second on average.  I suppose you might get peaks that are much higher than that, but in general, SQL Server can handle much higher transaction rates than what you seem to have.

If your table is fairly wide (lots of columns or a few really long ones) then you might want to consider clustering by a surrogate (IDENTITY) column.  Your volumes aren't enough to make for a bad hot-spot at the end of the table.  In combination with this, use indexes for any keys needed for data consistency (i.e. FK's) and retrieval (PK, natural key, etc).  Be careful about setting the fill factor on your indexes and consider rebuilding them during a periodic down-time window.

If your table is fairly narrow, then you could possibly consider clustering on the natural key, but you'll have to make sure that your response time expectations can be met.